# SQL server, check if varchar contains all zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

I need to write a function to check if a varchar variable value is all zeros.

As the variable is a varchar and not an int I am a bit lost. What would you do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a double-negative with a `LIKE` test:

```
@variable NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'
```

Which says the variable *isn't* composed of some number of characters, then a character that *isn't* a `0`, followed by some number of characters. The only strings that fail to match that `LIKE` expression are strings that only contain `0`s, and so we use the `NOT` to invert the result.

(This does also accept an empty string - whether you consider an empty string to be composed of only `0`s can be quite an interesting discussion - it certainly doesn't contain any *other* characters. A simple `LEN(@Variable)` test can be used if you do choose to reject this)